# Skype4com.dll not working for latest update

Tags: c#, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, skype4com

I was using Skype4com.DLL but it is deprecated not working with the skype latest updates. I was using it in a Skype plugin(windows application) to log in and make calls. As an alternative, I have found UCWA Skype Web SDK. (I'm not sure if this is the right alternative for SKype4Com.DLL)

I searched through internet and find support for skype4com is discontinued. The library is not working with the latest version of Skype.

```
static void skypeVar_MessageStatus(ChatMessage pMessage, TChatMessageStatus Status) // Skype's generated event for messages
{
    ChatMessage rMessage = pMessage.Chat.SendMessage_Fixed("Hello world!"); 
}
```

As a substitute, I thought UCWA can be used to call skype web methods. I'm trying to sign-in into the sample web SDK project. https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk

I have everything set up in the Azure portal all necessary permissions for Skype business are provided also the oauth2allowimplicitflow is set up to true.

As suggested in the AzureAD login I have setup the reply URL to https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk.

But I'm getting the below error:

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application:
>   'e9a70a77-0663-4f53-9f98-xxxxxxx'

Can anyone help in guiding me what should be used in the place of Skype4comm.DLL or how we can use Skype4comm.DLL with the latest version? If UCWA is the right solution then how can we fix the above error?

Comment: Could it be something as simple as your code adding a forward slash to the URL somewhere? To eliminate this possibility, could you add a forward slash on both places and see what happens? Sounds like a fix that would be too simple, but maybe it works.